# jquery toggle change image regarding status

Tags: jquery, toggle

I'm using jquery toggle to hide some content, which the user can "unfold" if he/she wants to see it. Here's a jsFiddle of it:

http://jsfiddle.net/yjs2P/

using this code:

```
$.noConflict();
function toggleDiv(divId) {
   jQuery("#"+divId).toggle($);
}
```

As you can see the first element is already opened with a "close"-image (red), two other elements are "closed" with "open"-images (orange).

Now I want to achieve that if the user clicks on one of the images, all toggle-elements get closed and the click-related element gets opened. When the element is opened the image should change to the other state, so if it's closed (orange) the image should be changed to open (red) and the other way round, too.

Can anyone provide me any hints to this issue?

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok how about this - first lets make a few changes to your html.

Lets not use id's but instead get into the mindset of referencing by class name. So for each of the content div's I added a **news-content** class

```
...
<div class="news-content" id="myContent">
...
<div class="news-content" id="myContent2">
...
<div class="news-content" id="myContent3">
...
```

Next lets remove the click handler from the hyperlinks href attribute (we'll add a handler in a minute with jQuery)

```
<a class="toggle" href="#">
```

Removed all your css and just made sure the news-content was hidden by default

```
.news-content {
    display: none;
}
```

**jQuery**

With those changes inplace, lets write a click handler for the hyperlinks so that it performs the toggle. Note: I used **slideUp** and **slideDown** instead of *toggle*.

**[Click here for the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yjs2P/4/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('a.toggle').click(function () {

        // select out the elements for the clicked item
        var $this = $(this),
            $root = $this.closest('.news-text'),
            $content = $root.find('.news-content'),
            $toggleImage = $this.find('img');

        // collapse all items except the clicked one
        $('.news-text').each(function () {
            var $itemRoot = $(this);
            if ($itemRoot == $root) return; // ignore the current
            var $itemContent = $itemRoot.find('.news-content');
            if ($itemContent.is(':hidden')) return; // ignore hidden items

            // collapse and set img
            $itemContent.slideUp(); 
            $itemRoot.find('.toggle > img').attr('src', 'http://www.70hundert.de/images/toggle-open.jpg');
        });

        // for the current clicked item either show or hide
        if ($content.is(':visible')) {
            $content.slideUp();
            $toggleImage.attr('src', 'http://www.70hundert.de/images/toggle-open.jpg');
        } else {
            $content.slideDown();
            $toggleImage.attr('src', 'http://www.70hundert.de/images/toggle-close.jpg');
        }

        // stop postback
        return false;
    });
});
```

### Updated - New Version of JQuery Handler

**[Click here for the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chrismoutray/3v9q9/)**

```
$('a.toggle').click(function () {

    var openImgUrl = 'http://www.70hundert.de/images/toggle-open.jpg',
        closeImgUrl = 'http://www.70hundert.de/images/toggle-close.jpg';

    var $newsItem = $(this).closest('.news-text'),
        $newsContent = $newsItem.find('.news-content'),
        isContentVisible = ($newsContent.is(':visible'));

    // slide up all shown news-items - but its expected that only one is visible at a time
    $('.news-text').find('.news-content').slideUp(function () { 
        // on animation callback change the img
        $('.news-text').find('.toggle > img').attr('src', openImgUrl);
    });

    if (!isContentVisible) { // if the new-item was hidden when clicked, then show it!
        $newsContent.slideDown(function () {
            // on animation callback change the img
            $newsItem.find('.toggle > img').attr('src', closeImgUrl);
        });
    }

    return false; // stop postback
});
```

Comment: Hi Chris! Thanks for your solution! I tried to implement it in my site, but unfortunately because of the "href="#"" inside the a-link the site gets a) reloaded (what I don't want it to!) and b) it changes the url so I get to the start-page...

Comment: javascript updated - make sure click handler returns false to stop the postback occurring

Comment: Thank you very much Chris! That did it for me! I really appreciate your help!

Comment: @henrywright see updated version of handler - a more elegant version?

Comment: @EMEm see updated version of handler - a more elegant version?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Tested it and it works great!

Comment: Just to note- I went down the ID route to start with but this is a far better solution. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function toggleDiv(divId) {
    jQuery('[id^=myContent]').not("#" + divId).hide()
    jQuery("#" + divId).toggle($);
    var $img = jQuery("#" + divId).next('p').find('img');
    var src = $img.attr('src');
    $img.attr('src', (src.indexOf('close') > -1) ? src.replace('close', 'open') : src.replace('open', 'close'));
}
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/yjs2P/1/)

Comment: Hi Palash! That's nearly what I wanted to achieve! regarding your DEMO you can see if I hit the 3rd image the first image stays as close (red), same if I click now on the 2nd image...the images stay red and should change to orange...

Comment: again, nearly ;) I open your Fiddle-DEMO, then I click on the 2nd image top open the element, the images changes to red (right!). Now I click the 2nd image again to close this element, the image stays red. Same issue with the other elements, if I click the images to open and close right after, the image stays red...sorry to bother you again, but I have no idea how to fix this last thing...